# How to set up interrupt registers on the stm32 microcontrollers?

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I wanted to toggle a led status by reading a push button status's using interrupt instead of polling. I'm using a Nucleo board F411 and a register based programming instead of that no sense HAL libraries(lol I'm just joking)

After reading the reference manual and the programming manual for the corresponding micro controller I thought that this code would work fine for the purpose of implementing interrupts...turns out it was not the case. I took at look at the debugging session to see how the corresponding registers changes and it does exactly as I need (the NVIC->ISERx, the priority bits, the unmasking bits, the rising or falling edge trigger, etc) so I actually have no idea what is wrong with my way of thinking about this problem.

By the way, I'm using a custom made (for me) class in order to easily set up any GPIO, I've tried this separately and I can say that the problem is not related to my library. You may think of this as just a configuration function for the GPIO as system_clock_config might be.

The thing is, whenever I push the button, nothing happens.

I get no compilation errors nor warnings.

Here is the code:

```
#include <main.h>
#include <GPIO_PORT.h>
#include <config.h>
#include <stm32f4xx.h>
#include <core_cm4.h>

/*GPIO_PORT is a custom made class that allows me to easily set any GPIO port as well 
 *as changing its attributes like pull up or pull down input mode, push-pull or open
 *drain output, change its mode (input or output), read and write to it, etc
 */

#define IO          GPIO_PORT


/*interrupt handler function for external interrupts from lines 10 to 15.
 * It's name goes according to the ones in the vector table generated in the startup.s file
 */
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler (void){

    EXTI->PR = (1 << 13);           //clears the pending interrupt from line 13. this is done by writing a 1 to the register.
    GPIOA->ODR ^= (1 << 5);         //toggle PORTA5 output (this is where the LED is connected to)
}


int main(void){

    /*system_clock_settings():
     * function that selects whether to use internal or external oscillator as clock source
     */
    system_clock_settings('I');

    /*HAL_Init():
     * I wanted to use a little delay
     */
    HAL_Init();

    IO led('A', 5 , 0);                     //creates an IO class object which resembles a LED connected to PORTA0(output GPIO)

    IO boton1('C', 13, 1);                  //creates an IO class object which resembles a push button connected to PORTC13
    boton1.pupd_selection(-1);              //method of the class IO that selects no pull up neither pull down mode for this input.

    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<14);                //enables system configuration controller.

    SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] = (1<<5);             //bits [4:7] 0010 selects PORTC13 as EXTI source for line 13.


    EXTI->IMR |= (1<<13);                   //unmasking line 13 for the corresponding interrupt to be able to be triggered.

    EXTI->RTSR |= (1<<13);                  //rising edge triggers interrupt on line 13.

    NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 1);    //sets the priority for the EXTI15_10 lines of EXTI

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);         //enables external interrupts coming from line 13

    while(1){


    }

}
```

Comment: `#include <core_cm4.h>` those files should not be included directly.  2. Buttons & EXTI are not good friends. Use timer interrupt (for example systick) and check pins periodically. Do not use magic numbers

Comment: @0___________  I included core_cm4.h to test if that solved the problem but it did not. I did not know that those files couldn't be included directly, I will for sure have that in mind for future development.

When you say magic numbers, are you referring to this for example:
IO led('A', 5 , 0); or this : RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<14); ?

thanks btw.

Comment: "nothing happens". Could you be more specific ? No interrupt ? You may joke about the HAL but it's still very useful to understand how the product has to be used.

Comment: before enabling the interrupts (to the core), poll your way through this.  enable at the peripheral, see the peripheral interrupt fire in its status register.  then look at the interrupt controller (raw if available) once you see that, then enable the interrupt, and poll for that.   at each step learn how to clear that interrupt at that layer.   then finally enable the interrupt into the core, and print something or write memory or something from the handler.  confirm it is clearing and completing.

Comment: using an interrupt for a pushbutton is horrible, you will get bounce it will hit the interrupt multiple times, sometimes may be faster than you can handle them.   probably want to learn to use the interrupts with a timer, then work your way up to something like this (for educational purposes, then for real applications read the buttons a different way).

Comment: if you try to do it all at once you will fail, for a while...if not a long time.

Comment: if you are using the hal, I would assume that there are both examples and libraries to help you.  try those.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean that was a bad one on me.
by "nothing happens" I mean that the led is not turning on as I expect it to do.
I actually think that HAL goes backwards with respect to proper learning of embedded system

Comment: @Juan_David, I don't agree, the HAL shows you what registers exactly must be written and how. it might not do it very efficiently for different reasons (mainly I think because it tries to adress all possible modes or use cases). When I don't know a peripheral I read the manual and then have a look at the HAL to see how it works. At the end I implement my own code.

Comment: Also, "the led is not turning on" is a bit short... Did you put a breakpoint in the interrupt handler ? Did you check the GPIO register values (for example in the debugger do you see the button GPIO value register switch to 1 when you press the button, etc...) ?

Comment: Manage a button and turn on a LED might look pretty obvious but in reality many things can go wrong since you are at the lowest possible level of interface with the HW

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean as I mentioned earlier on the post, I've checked the way in which the different configuration register changes (ISER,IP,IMR , etc).

when on the debug session running, when I push the button, the pending interrupt register sets at the corresponding line (EXT13) 

in short, NVIC and EXTI configuration register seem to be taking the values that I want and also the interrupt pending register also sets, but still I don't know how to proceed since I'm a beginner mostly with the debugging. I might post a few screenshots if you are willing to help me. Thanks BTW

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `EXTI15_10_IRQHandler `. if you think EXTI and NVIC are correctly configured, you should reach this function (provided it is defined in the vector table at the right position but I assume you didn't change the default vector table).

Answer (score 1):

Add :

```
NVIC_SetVector(EXTI15_10_IRQn, (uint32_t)&EXTI15_10_IRQHandler);
```

before your NVIC_Enable.
Best of luck to you!